# How do you modify XPKeywords using piexif?

Tags: python, python-3.x, piexif

```
import piexif

file = "download.jpeg"
exif_dict = piexif.load(file)
print(exif_dict)
exif_dict["0th"][piexif.ImageIFD.XPKeywords] = "keyword;".encode("utf-16be")
print(exif_dict)
piexif.insert(piexif.dump(exif_dict), file)
```

I tried to encode the keyword before adding it to the exif data dictionary but for some reason it is only getting stored as a tuple and not showing up when I explore the properties in Windows.

Comment: What is the data in the tuple that gets stored?

Comment: Did you figure out a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You're super close - `XPKeywords` is encoded in little endian (e.g. `utf-16le`):

```py
file = "download.jpeg"
exif_dict = piexif.load(file)
print(exif_dict)
exif_dict["0th"][piexif.ImageIFD.XPKeywords] = "keyword1, keyword2".encode("utf-16le")
print(exif_dict)
piexif.insert(piexif.dump(exif_dict), file)
```